# ObjA = ObjB in C++

Tags: c++, object

I found this exercise about C++ in a list and just couldn't solve it. Here it is: 
Let's say we have the following instruction:

```
ObjA = ObjB;
```

In which ObjA is an object of ClassA, and ObjB is an object of ClassB, this will run properly, if and only if there is:
A. A conversion function in ClassA
B. A conversion function in ClassB
C. A constructor in ClassA
D. A constructor in ClassB

There can be multiple correct answers. 
My problem with this exercise is that they are both objects, and, theoretically, you can't change the instance inside an object - and that is what I think the '=' would do there. Since there can be multiple correct answers, I thought, therefore, that none were correct. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run correctly if any of these is true:

1. There is an assignment operator in `ClassA` which takes an argument of type `ClassB`
2. There is an assignment operator in `ClassA` which takes an argument of type `X` and there is conversion function to type `X` in `ClassB`.
3. There is a conversion function to type `ClassA` in `ClassB`.

I don't know how/if these match to the ABCD choice(s) you have.

Answer (score 2):

You say:

> There can be multiple correct answers.

But that is directly contradicted by

> if and only if

Anyway, you need an implicit conversion from right hand side to left hand side.

Such a conversion can be expressed as a conversion operator in the rhs. type, or as a constructor in the lhs. type, or in this case (an assignment) as a special assignment operator in the lhs. type.

---

**EDIT**: Oh, I failed to consider a possible inheritance relationship (a so called slicing assignment), but I just saw that in the other answer. It's not mentioned in the answer alternatives you've been given. I think you should find some better quality training material…

Answer (score 1):

> My problem with this exercise is that they are both objects, and, theoretically, you can't change the instance inside an object - and that is what I think the '=' would do there.

That's not correct. You can certainly use the assignment operator between two objects, in some cases even if they're different types. This is what copy constructors, assignment operators and conversion operators are all about.

Here is a very simple example that demonstrates some of the possibilities:

```
std::string s1, s2;
const char* cstr = ...;
s1 = s2;
s1 = cstr;
```

That said, I think the question is very poorly worded. Specifically, the "if and only if" part means that none of the answers are entirely correct (even if some of them are partially correct). It also completely neglects the possibility that there could be an inheritance relationship between `ClassA` and `ClassB`.

> I found this exercise about C++ in a list

To be brutally honest, if this exercise is representative of the quality you find on that list, it might be worthwhile to consider going someplace else for your C++ exercises.

Comment: well, that is due the fact, that the operator = is overloaded to accept a (const) char*. A nifty read (not for NPE) but for Luan Nico in my eyes is this: http://www.icu-project.org/docs/papers/cpp_report/the_anatomy_of_the_assignment_operator.html